# Force Mathematica not to reduce a fraction

Tags: function-construction

I am interested in a function which would stop *Mathematica* reducing fraction.

If my input is `50/100`, *Mathematica* outputs `1/2`, I want it to output `50/100`. Any nice function which does this?

I need this because I want to define a recursive function with this behavior:

```
f[0]=50/100
f[n_]:=(Numerator[f[n-1]]+1)/(Denominator[f[n-1]]+1)
```

I want to obtain `f[1]=51/101`, not `f[1]=2/3`, which I get.

A more complicated example:

```
f[0]=50/100
f[n_]:=If[Mod[n,2]==0,(Numerator[f[n-1]+1])/n,Numerator[f[n-1]/(Denominator[f[n-1]‌​]+1)
```

This gets really annoying if I store 50/100 as {50,100}.

Comment: I need it because I am defining a recursive function, where I need the denominator and nominator of the previous element of the function. i.e. let's say my function is this:

f[0]=50/100
f[n_]=Nominator[f[n-1]]+1/Denominator[f[n-1]]+1

Then this is useless if mathematica reduces the fractions...

EDIT: First time here, no clue how to make enters:P

Comment: How about storing `f[0]={50,100}`? (and there is an "edit" button right below your question, I think it would be nice to include the example)

Comment: That's a possibility, but it is slower than just not reducing the fraction I would say. It will probably work for what I am doing, but I would still like to know if there is a generic function to achieve this.

Comment: Did that! (10 characters)

Comment: Well yeah, this is just a quick thing I typed up, the thing I really want to do is a bit more complicated. Also HoldForm just keeps "Numerator" as a string. I'll edit my orginal post with brackets.

Comment: Sorry, I am in a bit of a hurry, but perhaps you can find the answer to your question in the notebook Basic Overriding.nb you find here http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/3336/

Comment: Man, already five minutes have passed? So, here's the rest: Basically, you should redefine the basic functions behind "/" (Times, Power, Rational) to execute custom code that won't simplify but will display like a fraction. But you'll probably be better off by defining a new function to use instead of any division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one

```
f[0] = HoldForm[50]/HoldForm[100];

f[n_] := HoldForm[#] &[ReleaseHold@Numerator[f[n - 1]] + 1]/
    HoldForm[#] &[ReleaseHold@Denominator[f[n - 1]] + 1];

f[5]
```

> 55/105

The second example

```
f2[0] = HoldForm[50]/HoldForm[100];

f2[n_] := 
 If[Mod[n, 2] == 0, 
  HoldForm[#] &[ReleaseHold@Numerator[f[n - 1]] + 1]/HoldForm[#] &[n],
   Numerator[f[n - 1]]/HoldForm[#] &[ReleaseHold@Denominator[f2[n - 1]] + 1]]

f2[1]
```

> 50/101

---

More elegant approach consists in the definition of your own irreducible `Fraction`

```
Fraction /: MakeBoxes[Fraction[n1_, n2_], StandardForm] := MakeBoxes@HoldForm[n1/n2]

f[0] = Fraction[50, 100];
f[n_] := Fraction[#1 + 1, #2 + 1] & @@ f[n - 1];
f[5]
```

> 55/105

```
f2[0] = Fraction[50, 100];
f2[n_] := If[Mod[n, 2] == 0, Fraction[#1 + 1, n], Fraction[#1, #2 + 1]] & @@ f2[n - 1];
f2[1]
```

> 50/101

Comment: I think I sort of understand what this does, but I'm not entirely sure how I would apply it to the 2nd example, would it still work?

Comment: @matti0006 Yes, it is! See my update.

Comment: Awesome, this seems to do what I want. Not sure if it's actually faster than making a list in my case, but I'd never even heard of Holdform and it seems useful in other situations!

Comment: @matti0006 See also the second update! I think it is more elegant than numerous `HoldForm`/`ReleaseHold`.

Comment: This looks a lot more elegant, could you maybe elaborate on MakeBoxes though, mathematica's help function is not giving me enough insight to see exactly what it does. Also, what does the /: in Fraction mean? (Sorry, not been using mathematica for too long:))

Comment: `MakeBoxes` calls when *Mathematica* builds the output (in the `StandardForm` here). `/:` with `:=` is [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagSetDelayed.html). See also [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/4678)

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bundle!

Answer (score 1):

As mentionend in the comments, as a kind of "workaround", you could use:

```
f[0] = {50, 100}; f[x_] := f[x - 1] + 1
```

(using that `Plus` is `Listable`) which yields for `f[1]`:

> `{51,101}`

or using memoization:

```
f[0] = {50, 100}; f[x_] := f[x] = f[x - 1] + 1
```

On another note (or reading the comments, thanks @Kuba), you won't even need recurisivity here:

```
f[x_]:= f[0] + n
```

**EDIT**

For the extended example (I guess there might be a typo in your comment below), you could do:

```
ff[0] = {50, 100};
ff[x_] := If[EvenQ[x], {#1 + 1, x}, {#1, #2 + 1}] & @@ ff[x - 1];
ff /@ Range[10]
```

> `{{50, 101}, {51, 2}, {51, 3}, {52, 4}, {52, 5}, {53, 6}, {53, 7}, {54, 8}, {54, 9}, {55, 10}}`

I leave it to you to judge what's nicer to look at (and faster...)

Comment: I believe the real case would be interesting since here f[n_]:=(50+n)/(100+n) :)

Comment: uhm... I must be tired

Comment: This works in this simple case, as I said in the comments above, but as things get more complicated, this is less and less effective, say I want instead to do this:
f[0]=50/100
f[n]=If[Mod[n,2]==0,(Numerator[f[n-1]+1])/n,Numerator[f[n-1]/(Denominator[f[n-1]]+1)

Using suggested notation, this gets very unreadable with all the brackets, since you'll have to use f[n-1][[1]] and f[n-1][[2]]

Comment: I will add this to original question for better notation...

Comment: Edited my original post to show how problems can arise if you do something a bit more difficult, it is still possible to store it as a list (obviously), but it won't be very pretty code.

Comment: Hm, your solution is pretty elegant as well, I like this!