# Special fractions generator

Tags: evaluation, simplifying-expressions

Note that

```
  13/33, 1313 / 3333 , 131313 / 333333, ...
```

They are always equivalent fractions

Fraciones generate desire to have this property based
arbitrary numbers provided by my

something like

```
frac[N, D]
```

Edit

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for this?  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33030/force-mathematica-not-to-reduce-a-fraction

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Regarding the error shown in your screen copy, it's a known problem of the syntax checker not recognizing this variant of `Fold`. Don't worry.

Comment: Please learn how to upvote. See below and practice it!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
frac[n_Integer, d_Integer, s_Integer] := 
    Module[{m = 10^(Length@IntegerDigits@Max[d, n])},
          FoldList[Plus, Array[{n, d} m^# &, s, 0]]]

frac[33, 11, 5]

(*
 {{33, 11}, {3333, 1111}, {333333, 111111}, {33333333, 11111111}, 
  {3333333333, 1111111111}}
*)
```